# How do select one element in a while loop (Re-assign a variable inside a while loop)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

The program "loops and returns" all the entries in in a folder on the server.

but my problem is: When the user selects any of the returned entries, only the first element is returned.

How do I return the user selected entry?

p.s I'm a noob at php
modal refers to "bootstrap modal"

```
<?php
      include_once("include/main.inc.php");
$query ="SELECT job_id, job_logo, job_company, job_title, job_area, job_county FROM job_tbl"; 
          $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
              if (!$result) {
                  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
                  exit;
              }
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                     $id = $row['job_id'];
                    $d = $row['job_logo'];
                    echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">';
                    echo                '<a href ="#" ><h6>'.$row['job_title'] .'</h6>   </a>';
                    echo                '<a href ="#view" class = "btn btn-default" data-toggle = "modal">View</a>';
                    echo  '</div>'; 
                    }
          $memid = $row['member_id'];

          $query2 ="SELECT job_id, member_id, job_logo, job_category, job_description, job_skills, emp_type, job_experiance, job_vacancy, job_salary, expery_date, job_contact_name FROM job_tbl";  
          $modalResult = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());

              if (!$modalResult) {
                  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
                  exit;
              }
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($modalResult)){
                $d = $row['job_logo'];
                      echo '<div class = "modal fade" id= "view" role ="dialog">';
                      echo    '<div class ="modal-dialog">';
                      echo      '<div class = "modal-content">';
                      echo         '<div class ="modal-header">';
                      echo            '<h4>Contact Locate.ie</h4>';
                      echo          '</div>';
                      echo        '<div class= "modal-body">';
                      echo       '<div class ="container">';
                      echo     '<div class="jumbotron">';
                      echo      '<legend class= "scheduler-border">';
                      echo          '<h5>Description:</h5>';
                      echo          '<h6>'.$row['job_description'].'</h6>';
                      echo      '</legend>';
                      echo      '</div>';
                      echo     '</div>';
                      echo    '</div>';
                      echo    '</div></div></div>';
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please, if you're just starting to learn PHP, learn using the MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements and bind variables, rather than learning using the old, deprecated MySQL extension.

Comment: And I creating a mobile app of the website, that's why I'm using all old conventions

Answer (score 0):

You wrote :

```
while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($modalResult))
    {
        $d = $row['job_logo'];
        echo      "<img src=\"http://www.foo.ie/images/job/".$d."\" >";
    }
```

It's probably a copy/paste typo. Shouldn't it be :

```
while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($modalResult))
    {
        $d = $query2['job_logo'];
        echo      "<img src=\"http://www.foo.ie/images/job/".$d."\" >";
    }
```

Also, as adviced before, try to learn PDO/prepared statements

Comment: When I change it to $query2 nothing happens,